# Algorithm for grouping IP ranges and detect outliers

Tags: algorithm, ip, bigdata

I have a large DB like so (operator name, ip):

```
+-------+----------------+
|Name   |IP              |
+-------+----------------+
|A      |41.74.63.255    |
+-------+----------------+
|B      |168.167.255.255 |
+-------+----------------+
+ ...   | ...            |
```

I would like to automatically build a list of "valid ranges" for operators, based on their **appearance frequency in the DB** IE:

```
Operator "A" -> [(range A), (range B), (range C)...] 
Operator "B" -> [(range A)...]
```

Some sort of clustering, then detect if a new IP from operator A falls inside a valid cluster, or is it an outlier.

What would be a good place to start?

Comment: What do you consider a "valid range"?

Comment: a valid range is based on the majority of the data, so if most of the records are from 41.74.63.0 - 41.74.63.255 than 168.167.255.255 is an outlier and not in the valid range

Comment: Shlomi is right, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are might be two approaches.

1. Some kind of [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)
2. Some kind of mapping (with certain assumptions).

#### Kind of Merge Sort

Or rather sort then merge. Straightforward approach, easy to understand and implement, but might be slow and inefficient.

```
SRC_LIST = (operator, ip) // source list of (operator, IP)
SORTED_IPS[] = (ip) // map of per-operator lists of sorted IPs
RANGES[] = (startIP, endIP) // map of per-operator lists of ranges

// sort IPs to per-operator lists of IPs
for E in SRC_LIST
    SortInsertIP(SORTED_IPS[E.operator], E.ip)

// merge continuous IPs into ranges
for OP in SORTED_IPS
    for IP in SORTED_IPS[OP]
        MergeIP(RANGES[OP], IP)

// sort merged lists based on their appearance frequency
```

#### Kind of Mapping

That might be very efficient and fast, but imposes few preconditions:

1. There are just IPv4 addresses, i.e. no IPv6.
2. The IP addresses in the DB must be rather /24 prefixes, i.e. always end with `.255` or `.0`
3. Number of `operators` is limited, ideally up to 255 to fit into a byte.

If those are true, we might use just first 3 bytes of the IPv4 as an index to a 2^24 table of `operators`. Then we just merge consecutive indexes.

```
SRC_LIST = (operator, ip) // source list of (operator, IP)
OPERATORS[] - (idx) // map each operator to an index starting form 1
TBL24[2^24] = (op_idx) // table of 2^24 operators, where 0 is unused entry
RANGES[] = (startIP, endIP) // map of per-operator lists of ranges

// map DB to TBL24 table
for E in SRC_LIST
    op_idx = GetOperatorIndex(OPERATORS[], E.operator)
    ip_idx = uint32(E.ip) >> 8 // convert 32-bit IPv4 to 24-bit index
    TBL24[ip_idx] = op_idx

// find consecutive operators in the map
startIdx = 0
while startIdx < 2^24
    endIdx = startIdx + 1
    while TBL24[startIdx] == DIR[endIdx]
        endIdx = endIdx + 1
        if endIdx == 2^24
            break

    // append found range to the per-operator list
    if TBL24[startIdx] != 0 // i.e. non-empty
        AppendList(RANGES[TBL24[startIdx]], (startIdx << 24, endIdx << 24))

    startIdx = endIdx + 1

// sort merged lists based on their appearance frequency
```

There is a way to use not just /24 prefixes, but also a more specific prefixes as well. Please have a look at [Routing Lookups in Hardware at Memory Access Speeds](http://tiny-tera.stanford.edu/~nickm/papers/Infocom98_lookup.pdf) paper or on a [software implementation of DIR-24-8 algorithm](http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/prog_guide/lpm_lib.html) in DPDK.